# How to print continuously data from telnet with telnetlib (python 3.7)

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, real-time, telnet, telnetlib

I want to print continuously data (real time) from telnet with telnetlib (python 3.7)
but no resalt becouse the fonction read_all don't stop

```
import telnetlib
tn = telnetlib.Telnet('10.205.61.60', port=9101, timeout=10)
v=tn.read_all()
print(v)
```

Comment: Output: D:\walid2\venv\Scripts\python.exe D:/walid2/gggg.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/walid2/gggg.py", line 5, in <module>
    v=tn.read_all()
  File "C:\Users\RTOMOSE\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\telnetlib.py", line 333, in read_all
    self.fill_rawq()
  File "C:\Users\RTOMOSE\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\telnetlib.py", line 524, in fill_rawq
    buf = self.sock.recv(50)
socket.timeout: timed out

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Try `read_some()` per docs at https://docs.python.org/2/library/telnetlib.html